# What is the time complexity for a clear function is std::map according to big O?

Tags: c++, dictionary, time-complexity

What is the time complexity for  a clear function is std::map?
Would I be right in saying that it is O(1)?

Comment: It has to destroy all the member objects. Sounds like O(n).

Comment: @BoPersson: but what if the elements had a trivial destructor ?

Comment: Then it would run faster. :-) The actual time taken is `k*n` where `k` depends on the type of the member objects. But in big O terms, it is still O(n) even if `k` is very small.

Comment: @BoPersson: maybe, maybe not. [`is_trivially_destructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) is a compile-time trait so it could deduce at compile-time that no such action is needed.

Comment: Gcc's vector implementation does this optimization, in fact. The map's doesn't seem to.

Comment: @jrok: the `map` has to call `deallocate` on each node anyway, I am afraid, so the optimizer can be trusted to inline the `destroy` call to nothing and there is no need for additional code.

Answer (score 7):

The Standard says in **[associative.reqmts]/8** *Table 102*:

> `a.clear()` <=> `a.erase(a.begin(), a.end())`  linear in `a.size()`

So it is actually mandated to be O(N).

---

**EDIT:** summing up the various bits.

To remove a node, a `map` does two operation:

1. Call the allocator `destroy` method to destroy the element
2. Call the allocator `deallocate` method to deallocate the memory occupied by the node

The former can be elided in code (checking for `is_trivially_destructible`), and actually it is generally done in `vector` for example. The latter is unfortunately trickier, and no trait exists, so we must rely on the optimizer.

Unfortunately, even if by inlining the optimizer could completely remove the `destroy` and `deallocate` nodes, I am afraid it would not be able to realize that the tree traversal is now useless and optimize *that* away too. Therefore you would end up in a Θ(N) traversal of the tree and nothing done at each step...

Comment: +1 Finally someone to cite the "only reliable" source on this.

Comment: Since the question was posted, it's been clear that the worst-case behaviour for any non-trivial destructor was O(N), but does the standard saying linear there not confirm that worst-case rather than eliminate the possibility that an implementation could achieve O(1)?

Comment: @TonyDelroy: It's an interesting question. The Standard precises it cannot be worse than O(N) but I certainly hope it does not constrain applications not to optimize. I think the *as-if* rule still holds, and as long as the observational behavior is similar optimizations could be applied.

Comment: O(1) is O(N) so an O(1) implementation satisfies the O(N) requirement.

Comment: O(N) just says that there exists an `n` and a `k` such that for `N > n` the thing being measured (time / CPU ticks) is less than `kN`. An O(1) process can satisfy this with whatever `n` satisfies the equivalent O(1) requirement and `k = k/n` for the O(1) k.

Comment: "I am afraid it would not be able to realize that the tree traversal is now useless" - quite possibly you're right in practice, but in principle an optimizer could remove a tree traversal simply by noting that the whole block of code has no observable side-effects -- nothing is `volatile`, nothing is written to, no I/O, and everything inlined so no calls to unknown code. But this is all supposing that `deallocate` is a no-op, which means an allocator that needs extra help from the user to actually free anything.

Answer (score 2):

The [cplusplus reference site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/clear/) claims it has linear complexity in the container's size as the destructor of each element must be called.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a template, it may be known at compile time that destruction in a no-op for the type (e.g. `std::map<int>`), so the need to destroy members isn't a good basis for deducing a necessary worst-case performance.  Still, the compiler must visit every node of the binary tree, releasing the heap memory, and the number of nodes relates linearly to the number of elements (that `erase()` only invalidates iterators/references/pointers to the erased element, `insert()` doesn't invalidate any etc. all evidence the 1:1 relationship).

So, it's linear, but because of the need to clean up the heap usage even if element destructors aren't needed....

(Interestingly, this implies that a `std::map<>`-like associative container - or perhaps `std::map<>` itself with a clever custom allocator - could be made O(1) for elements with trivial no-op destructors if all the memory was allocated from a dedicated memory pool that could be "thrown away" in O(1).)

Comment: What if the map is allocated on an arena or object pool which could release the memory in O(1)?

Comment: I already challenged the destructors calls (for `trivially_destructible` values), now let me challenge the memory deallocation. Is it mandated by the Standard that the `map` cannot keep the allocated nodes in a pool for later reuse ;) ?

Comment: @DeadMG: I am afraid that the generic template would still call `deallocate` on each and every node, it cannot know that the allocator is pool-based.

Comment: @MatthieuM: you can provide a custom allocator with trivial deallocate though... again this is resolved at compile time.

Comment: @DeadMG: Actually, it is interesting. Because it suggest that with more traits, an allocator could expose to the caller than `destroy` and `deallocate` are no-op so that the caller could take advantage of it; unfortunately it would be non-standard.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: not really, you would still pay the cost of traversing the tree; even if on each tree you're doing nothing. I don't think an optimizer would be smart enough to realize that the traversal itself is now useless (and I'd love to be proven wrong :D)

Comment: @Matthieu: a compelling analysis... does look grim!  Cheers

Comment: If `deallocate` can be inlined and optimzied away, and the tree traversal written as a loop, then enough optimizers are able to eliminate that empty loop. Doesn't need a special convention.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, all the clean-operation's complexity is O(n), because you need to destuct these objects one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to erase all elements it'll take O(N) complexity, but you can assign it to empty map each iteration, instead of clean

```
map<int,int>m1,m2;
```

computations on m1 updated

```
m1.clear()//instead of O(N)
```

do

```
m1=m2; //O(1)
```

Comment: This still triggers the destruction of all elements in m1, so it is still O(N) ;-)